# How to invoke a child job asynchronously

Tags: java, talend

I'm using Talend Open Studio. I want to invoke a child job (tRunJob) from a parent job, but continue the execution of parent job without waiting for the execution of the child job to complete.
My objective here is to create a job whose only purpose is the triggering of other jobs. So when I'm receiving a request for XYZ talend job to be executed, this job should simply start execution of XYZ talend job and return to listening for new triggers.
How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two ways to trigger a child Talend job from a parent Talend job asynchronously

**Using Iterate link**

[image: Parallel execution using Iterate link]
You can use an Iterate link to enable parallel execution. Click on the Iterate link and select 'Enable parallel execution' and set number of parallel threads.

**Using Java**

You can build the child job, and then execute the child job from the parent Job using plain Java (using a tJava component).

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ "bash", "-c", "sh path/to/child_job.sh &"});
```

Make sure to add the '&' at the end of the command, else it will synchronously wait for execution to finish.